# when removing a child element I get an error that it may have already been removed in a "blur" event

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a dynamic element added to a LI element. When I remove it in a "blur" event it works fine. But when I attempt to remove the element from the parent in a "keydown" event it throws an error that the child may already have been removed in a blur event. 
The item is removed as expected and the flow continues but I get an error every time on the "keydown" event.

```
    // I get the error in this event. 
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        value = this.value;
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
        callBack.call(null,[value]);
      }
    });
    //no error removing the element here
    input.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
      value = this.value;
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
      callBack.call(null,[value]);  
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trigger the blur event on the input, only the blur event fires.

When you trigger the keydown event that removes the input, the blur event *also* fires as a consequence of that removal, and tries to remove an input that is already gone.

To see this in action, check out this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/kDKVy/

```
var input = document.getElementById('foo');
var valueDisplay = document.getElementById('value');

var value;

input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        value = this.value;
        valueDisplay.value = value;
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    }
});

input.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
    console.log('BLUR');
    value = this.value;
    valueDisplay.value = value;
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
});
```

Open up your console. First, type something in the red box and then click away to trigger the blur event. Notice that it works nicely and you see "BLUR" in the console.

Run the fiddle again. Now, type something in the red box and hit enter. Notice that you get the "BLUR" message in your console before the error.

Make sense?